# Python Error ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]

Tags: python, sockets

I am experimenting with import sockets in python and I have a client.py and a server.py and when server.py  receives a message from client.py I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/echo_server.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = conn.recv(1024)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

My full code is:

```
import socket
host = '' 
port = 12345
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))

print(host , port)
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:

    data = conn.recv(1024)
    data = str(data)

    if not data: break

    print("Client Says: "+data)
    conn.sendall(b"Server Says:Message Received")


input(">")
conn.close()
```

Can someone tell me what this error is and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement `if not data` is equivalent to writing `if data != ""`, while the empty string your server receives is `b''`. You have several options to fix it.

`data = conn.recv(1024).decode()` is the proper way to allocate the data sent by the client. You can now `print(data)` or compare `data` to an empty string.

If you still don't want to `decode()` your message you could change your if statement to `if data != b''` or `if data is not None`.

#### Update

If it wasn't clear, your `str(data)` conversion causes the if statement to work unproperly, which is set to `False` without allowing you to break when a client disconnects.

Comment: Thank You for that, I used the .decode and it worked. Thank You very much

Comment: `if not data: break` is perfectly fine for checking for empty string (either `bytes` or `str` type).  Zero values, empty strings, empty containers (lists, dicts, tuples, etc.) are all considered false.

Comment: Correct though notice that he tried to process his data with `str()` instead of `decode()`, which caused the `if statement` not to work properly. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Right, the `if not data: break` should be immediately after the `recv`, and yes, `str(data)` on a bytes object is incorrect.  There's also the normal beginner issue of assuming TCP is message-based and not a byte stream, so the data received could be incomplete and a direct `.decode` could fail due to a multibyte UTF-8 character being split across two receives.